# Make Clang-Format give detailed error when there is a format problem

Tags: clang-format

As the title suggests I'm running Clang-Format on my code in order for it to show me if there are any format error...

The thing I wanna know is if there is a way to make the output more detailed, because every time it fails it does it with the same error:

```
error: code should be clang-formatted [-Wclang-format-violation]
```

like, is there any way for it to show me the specific violation?

I'm running clang like this:

```
clang-format -style=file --dry-run --Werror
```

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Hey, maybe this script can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50872482/7674702 It outputs a diff of what you need to change