# Make git-clang-format return an error code when there are changes

Tags: git, clang-format

`git clang-format` is a handy tool to run `clang-format` on only the lines touched by a git patch. I want to stop myself accidentally committing and pushing patches that I've forgotten to run git-clang-format on. E.g. by adding a check to `.git/hooks/pre-commit` that makes sure `git clang-format HEAD~1` has nothing to do. However it doesn't look like the return code ever changes.

`clang-format` itself has `--dry-run -Werror`: [Can clang-format tell me if formatting changes are necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866609/can-clang-format-tell-me-if-formatting-changes-are-necessary)

Unfortunately it doesn't look like git-clang-format supports it, or has a way to forward on the argument. Is there a programmatic way to know if there are changes?

```
$ git clang-format -Werror --diff HEAD~1 -q
usage: git clang-format [OPTIONS] [<commit>] [<commit>] [--] [<file>...]
git-clang-format: error: unrecognized arguments: -Werror
```

Comment: Given that [git-clang-format is a simple Python program](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/aa231e4be75ac4759c236b755c57876f76e3cf05/tools/clang-format/git-clang-format#L167-L181), you could easily *add* some kind of exit-status option to it. Take a look at the lines in the link.

Comment: There's an idea. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I'm checking stdout to see if there were no changes in a `--diff`:

```
# Use -q to suppress 'no changes' message and then grep for any lines printed
git clang-format --diff HEAD~1 -q | grep '^' --color=never

# Alternative: use awk to search for the 'no changes' messages and return the result
# This is a bad because the message could change in future versions
git clang-format --diff HEAD~1 | awk '/^no modified files to format|^clang-format did not modify any files/{result=1;}/^/{print} END{ exit !result}'
```

Since both use a pipe, color in the diff is removed. To keep color in the output during a `.git/hooks/pre-commit` hook I'm running it twice... :(

```
#!/bin/bash
git clang-format --diff HEAD~1 -q
if git clang-format --diff HEAD~1 -q | grep -m 1 '^' >/dev/null; then
    echo >&2 "Failed clang-format check. Run: git clang-format HEAD~1"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`git-clang-format` [now](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/357afd952852db0be3f690f8b647bd4b02f38cad) returns error code 1

You should update your LLVM installation.