# Enforce code style from editorconfig in build in C++

Tags: c++, editorconfig

In c# where is a setting "EnforceCodeStyleInBuild" that allows to fail build if code doesn't align with rules from .editorconfig.
C++ supports editorconfig as well, but I can't find a way how to fail build if there is a mistake in formatting as we can do in c#.

I expect that editirconfig in c++ can affect build.

Comment: In C++ clang-format is industry standard. It doesn't "fail the build" it just reformats code. I never seen someone would fail build if formatting is not aligned with clang-format settings.

Comment: You can change your build to run `clang-format` and check for changes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866609/can-clang-format-tell-me-if-formatting-changes-are-necessary